# C#: How do i make sense of generics like Action<IEnumerable<Customer>, Exception>

Tags: c#, generics

i am new to c#. coming from mainly PHP background or basic VB.

i understand that `IEnumerable<Customer>` is something like a list of customer.

but what is `Action<IEnumerable<Customer>, Exception>`. an action of type `IEnumerable<Customer>` & `Exception`. doesnt seem to make too much sense to me.

Comment: When I see a method that has an argument like this I hit F1. Usually MSDN will have an example that will help make sense.

I guess this is just syntax you will eventually get used to - kind of like variable declarations in C++ ...

Comment: I don't know there is Action<T1,T2> generic type. Maybe the same as Func<T1,T2>?

Comment: @LLS: No, Action<T1,T2> takes two parameters and returns void. Func<T1,T2> takes one paremeter (T1) and returns T2. The difference between Action and Func is that Action returns void and Func returns the last generic parameter.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo : Thanks, I've only met Action and Action<T>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, `Action` and `Func` are function pointers, you can pass them around just like any other object and you invoke them in exactly the same way that you call other functions. Essentially `Action<IEnumerable<Customer>, Exception>` means:

- A function which returns void, and accepts two parameters of types `IEnumerable<Customer>` and `Exception` as an input.

This would be a compatible signature:

```
void DoStuff(IEnumerable<Customer> customer, Exception e) { ... }
```

Sometimes long generic signatures like the one you have can be cumbersome to work with, it can occasionally be nicer to move those params into a single object such as:

```
class CustomerContext {
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}
```

At least then you can pass around an `Action<CustomerContext>`, which can save some typing and sanity :)

Comment: (Of course, you could also declare a new [delegate type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28VS.80%29.aspx).)